# Show data in weekly or monthly intervals

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, intervals, timeserieschart

I am working with dataset that contains data in the following format: YYYY-WW.I converted it to this format DD-MM-YYYY, using this:

```
data['Date'] = data['Date'].apply(lambda x: week_to_date(x).strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
```

Now I want to show  the data with weekly or monthly intervals but I am getting some misleading chart that probably are wrong.

When I plot the chart, using this code:

```
plt.plot(data['Date'], data['Sales Volume'])
```

My chart looks very busy:
[image: chart]

I would like to show data with weekly or monthly intervals but when I try to use resampling

```
data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

monthly_data = data.resample('W').count()

plt.figure().set_figwidth(30)

plt.plot(monthly_data.index, monthly_data['Sales Volume'], label='Monthly', marker='o', linestyle='-')
```

My graph looks like:
[image: graph2]

Comment: Pandas needs date, not strong objects to resample

Comment: why don't you use `pd.to_datetime`? as @PaulH said, saying to resample every `W` does not work if the data is an object, it needs to be datetime